# My interest in 'x' CULTIVATED many years ago...?

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests

Is there anything wrong with saying the following?

My interest in Japan **cultivated** many years ago after taking part in .....

I initially used the verb **stemmed** as I want to indicate that it began after taking part in '...', but I was told it did not make sense.

Comment: *To cultivate* means ["to nurture; to foster; to tend"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cultivate). And it's transitive. It does not mean "to stem, to originate", which are intransitive. So yeah, what you have does not make sense, and is ungrammatical to boot.

Comment: It can be valid if *cultivated* is used as a participle. *My interest in Japan, cultivated many years ago after taking part in a penpal exchange with a girl from Nara from fourth to eighth grade, has resurfaced in my adult life*. Interestingly,  *stemmed* would mean the opposite in that usage— to dam up or stanch something.

Comment: No matter what is being cultivated, the word to me implies a level of care that is reminiscent of gardening.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to say "My interest in Japan **was cultivated** many [...]".

If you use only the word "cultivate", that would be the active version. For instance, you would say "I have cultivated my friends interest in politics" to express that YOU made him care about it.

You however want to express that your interest was cultivated and thereby grew bigger, not that your interest cultivated something.

Answer (score 1):

A different word entirely might be better--"cultivated," regardless of how you use it, implies someone has intentionally done the cultivating; and if done "years ago," implies it ended. How about "my interest, sparked..." or "My interest blossomed..." "My interest, captured ..."? Or the like.

Answer (score -1):

The use of "was cultivated" would 'feel better'; however, you can also add punctuation to the original and be just as clear:

My interest in Japan, cultivated many years ago, after taking part in…